# New Pandas dataframe column not changing

Tags: python, pandas

I've got this

```
def email(cell):
pattern = '[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9a-z.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}'
try:
    x = re.search(pattern, cell)
    return x.group(0)
except AttributeError:
    pass

def name(cell):
middle = '[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]\.\s[A-Za-z]+'
no_middle = '[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+'
try:
    x = re.search(middle, cell)
    return x.group()
except AttributeError:
    try:
        x = re.search(no_middle, cell)
        return x.group()
    except AttributeError:
        pass


def rename_cells(dataframe):
dataframe['J'] = ''
dataframe['K'] = ''
for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    row['J'] = email(row.I)
    row['K'] = name(row.I)
    x = row.I.replace([str(row.K), str(row.J)], '')
    row.I = x
```

My data is filled with various items from column's A-H, and column 'I' has a paragraph that I am matching using regex to pull out certain items. I've tested the regex and the pulls work fine, however, when I try to use the rename_cells function, I end up with columns J and K blank with column I the same as before and no replacements. Any thoughts?

Sample Data:

```
df_stack = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'],'B':['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'C': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'D': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'E': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'F': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'G': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'H':['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'I':['John A. Smith johnsmith@gmail.com','Stacy Smith stacysmith@gmail.com','Jimbo G. Smith jimbosmith@gmail.com', 'John Apple johnapple@gmail.com']})
```

That should create a similar style dataframe. I would like something akin to this:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'A':['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'],'B':['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'C': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'D': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'E': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'F': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'G': ['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'H':['aaa','bbb','ccc', 'eee'], 'I':['John A. Smith', 'Stacy Smith ','Jimbo G. Smith', 'John Apple'], 'J': ['johnsmith@gmail.com', 'stacysmith@gmail.com', 'jimbosmith@gmail.com', 'johnapple@gmail.com']})
```

Thanks for any insight

Comment: You're operating on a copy not a view, you need to read this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: Also you can probably generate the new rows by calling `apply` which would be much easier to read than what you're doingnow

Comment: so I tried replacing the row['J'] and row['K'] with row.loc('J') and row.loc('K') but that ended up in some error messages. Am I just going about this all wrong by the for looping through index and row? Should I just apply a function directly to row.loc('I') ?

Comment: Post some sample data and desired result, thanks

Comment: added some dataframe functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all your doing is just separating the name from the email, a crude way of doing this which will work your dataset is this:

```
In [22]:

df_stack['I'], df_stack['J'] = df_stack.I.str.split(' ').str[:-1].str.join(' '), df_stack.I.str.split(' ').str[-1]
df_stack
Out[22]:
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H               I  \
0  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa   John A. Smith   
1  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb     Stacy Smith   
2  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  Jimbo G. Smith   
3  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee      John Apple   

                      J  
0   johnsmith@gmail.com  
1  stacysmith@gmail.com  
2  jimbosmith@gmail.com  
3   johnapple@gmail.com
```

So this uses the vectorised `str` method to split on spaces, we can easily get the email as it's the last element in the split list, for the name we take the rest of the elements and rejoin using a space.

**EDIT**

For the email bit we can just use the same regex and call `findall`, for the other bit we just pass the func as a param to `apply:

```
In [39]:

import re

def name(cell):
    middle = '[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]\.\s[A-Za-z]+'
    no_middle = '[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+'
    try:
        x = re.search(middle, cell)
        return x.group()
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            x = re.search(no_middle, cell)
            return x.group()
        except AttributeError:
            pass
df_stack['J'] = df_stack['I'].str.findall('[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9a-z.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}').str[0]
df_stack['I'] = df_stack['I'].apply(name)
df_stack
Out[39]:
     A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H               I  \
0  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa  aaa   John A. Smith   
1  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb  bbb     Stacy Smith   
2  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  ccc  Jimbo G. Smith   
3  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee  eee      John Apple   

                      J  
0   johnsmith@gmail.com  
1  stacysmith@gmail.com  
2  jimbosmith@gmail.com  
3   johnapple@gmail.com
```

Comment: ah, that would be much easier but the sample data is unfortunately much simpler than the real values, the names and email addresses are embedded in a much larger string which is why I needed to use those functions email and name

Comment: @nahata5 OK, I've updated my code, we can use your email regex directly as a param to `findall`, for the name bit we can just pass that as the param to `apply`

Comment: thats the way to do it, thanks that worked perfectly. I wish I understood that copy versus view stuff a little more. I understand that my function was applied to the wrong one.. but how else can you loop through the rows and cell data without it?

Comment: You can still do that but you need to use the indexing methods as I've stated already and not use the subscript notation, the thing to take away from all this is to always look for a vectorised solution